# How to insert and display multiple checkbox values to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in my sql database

Advert table (advert_id, amenities, title, description)

amenities table (amenities_id, amenities, description)

My create advert form gets and displays values for amenities from the amenities table.

I am trying to save the advert into the advert table, but I don't know how to save selected amenities into the advert table. Also I don't know how to get values for the amenities field when displaying the advert.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in checkbox write html code like
    
now use $checkeg = $_POST["your checkbox name"];
then insert the $checkeg to the table or to the db

Comment: How can I get the MySQL table coloumn (amenities) to accept multiple values such as garden, garage etc

Comment: If i understand what you mean you want insert multiple values to one column? If it is right. Concatination is the right way for example insert garden, and garage do like this
$multiple = $_POST["garden"]. " ". $_POST["garage"];
then insert the $multiple into the aminities column. The dot is use to concatinate multiple variables or string and etc i hope it help?

Comment: The amenities coloumn in advert table does not take multiple values